# Trying to get the hang of JavaScript Animations

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm new here and new to JavaScript too.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is making a image rise from the footer to the center  of the page, I've worked out how to do it with CSS. But I wanted it to rise up, when the page loads by itself.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or show me some examples etc. I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: There are at least two great projects from where you can learn: [**animate.css**](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and [**jQuery.transit**](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit). Their source code should give you some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to perform an animation before/while a page is being loaded?
Most modern browsers load the website before animating anything.

There is an alternative though. You can leave most of the content out of the page, except for the animation of course. When the website is loaded, animation starts and you can use AJAX to get your content.

That would mean that while your animation is running, content is loaded.

I'm creating a demo right now... hold on!

---

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gWhtQ/

I've used `window.addEventListener('load', init, false);` to wait for the javascript to run untill the page is loaded.

After it's loaded, an `XMLHttpRequest` object is created which get's an other file while your page runs normally.

Once content is loaded, I add the response using `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`.

Dont mention the content. I just used a random CSS file available.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much Tim, this is exactly what I was looking for. Wish me luck and thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome! On stack overflow you can accept answers to show people the right answer in case anyone has the same question. Please click the big "V" left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out with Javascript  it's probably going to be much easier to get started with animations using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

jQuery will allow you to focus on what you are trying to do and not worry too much about browser differences, ready events etc. Also if you're more interested in how jQuery is doing it's animations you can check out the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

Comment: Thanks man, great resources!

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Addy Osmani's post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/). To do the animation while the page is loading you will need to put the image at the top of your html body so that the browser stops and loads it first, before the rest of your page. Then in your script you could test if the element is present in the DOM and then start the animation when it is. However, this will really hinder the performance. I'd advise doing the animation after the page loads which you can easily test using jQuery. This way the image can be placed anywhere in your html body and your script can be placed at the very end to improve loading time. Paul Irish also has a [good post](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) on doing animation.